# How to set the value form Materialize's Switches using jquery

Tags: materialize

I'm using the Materialize library and I'm trying to set the value for the switches . How to set the value for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'checked' property:

```
$('#yourswitch').prop('checked', false);
```